# Django render page then load data from API response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

My view is currently waiting for around 1000 synchronous API queries and it takes a few seconds to render the page with all the data. What is the best practice in Django to make this faster or perhaps render a clean page then load data as it fetches. Should I go asyncio, multiprocess, threading, or make API calls using javascript instead of backend and then fill the DOM?

Comment: *"or make API calls using javascript instead of backend and then fill the DOM"* - That's generally my preferred approach.  Show the user a UI as soon as possible and include some visual indicator(s) for things which are still "loading".  Then make AJAX requests to fetch that data.

Comment: @David Thanks, follow up question then. Would I have a for loop calling async AJAX requests inside the document.onload/window.onload? If I do will the data display 1 by 1 or display when the whole loop is done? I'd prefer the data displaying 1 by 1.

Comment: I can't really tell you what will happen from code I can't see or results you haven't demonstrated.  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.